# CAN'T HIDE THE NAV ITEMS FROM THE FRONT-END UMBRACO-8

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco8

The  code below has been written in MVC5 controller. It throws an error 
"Object does not contain definition of Where". The "IsToShow" is DocumentType
having a control "true/false" and this is used on every Document Type as a composition and its value is set on content template like UmbracoNaviHide.

```
public List<NavigationList> GetSubNavigationList()
 { 
     IPublishedContent page = Umbraco.Content(pageId); 
     var subPages = page.Children.Where("IsToShow");//Error Line 
 }
```

Comment: Is Where a method supplied by Umbraco? It doesn't look like the LINQ one because you're not passing it a Lambda function, but if you did mean LINQ then you probably need `using System.Linq;`, and you probably then meant to test a property on the object e.g. `,.Where(page => page.IsToShow)` rather than passing a string. Where did you get this code from? Are you sure the syntax is correct?

Comment: Or when you say 'throws an error' do you mean this is a runtime exception you're getting not a compile time error? So the type of page.Children is dynamic object not a collection?

Comment: hey, thanks for replying  . Iam sure this is the right syntax from what i can tell this code works perfectly with umbraco 7 but somehow it is not running on version-8  and yes it is a run time error

Comment: What if you go page.Children().Where(...) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query Where with Lamdba and property/equals like this in U8.

```js
var subPages = page.Children.Where(x => x.GetProperty("isToShow").Value().Equals(true));
```